# Instantiation error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in **Haskell**

```
type Year = Int
data MonthData = Jan | Feb | March | Apr | Mar | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec deriving ( Eq, Show, Ord )
type Month = ( MonthData, Year )

days :: Month -> Int -> Int
days( m, d ) = 31
```

When I try to execute it in the Hugs interpreter, I have the following error:

```
ERROR Instance of Num (Int -> Int) required for definition of days
```

The error is located on the last line of my code, FYI.

Could anyone explain me why I have this error? I can't figure out how my function call doesn't match my function declaration.

Comment: Chepner answered before I could, but just to add a little context to his (correct!) answer in case it helps you out - in Haskell, function definition/application is done using spaces, rather than brackets and commas. This trips a lot of people up coming from C-like languages - what would be `x(y, z)` becomes `x y z`.

Comment: This question clearly comes from the point of view of learning Haskell; however, for anybody who finds this question by search and is trying to use (rather than learn) Haskell, take a look at [gregorianMonthLength](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:gregorianMonthLength) from the `time` package for this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type declaration says that `days` (ignoring currying) takes two arguments. Your definition, though, says `days` takes a single tuple as an argument. Change the type to

```
days :: Month -> Int
days (m, d) = 31
```

or change the definition to

```
days :: Month -> Int -> Int
days (m, d) x = 31
```

depending on what `days` is supposed to do.

Your definition only specifies the first of the two arguments expected given your type. Since `days :: Month -> Int -> Int`, then `days (m, d) :: Int -> Int`. Since you said the return value was `31` (which has type `Num a => a`) Haskell attempted to unify `a` with `Int -> Int`. (That is, treated `31` as a function that takes an integer and returns an integer.) There is no `Num` instance for `Int -> Int`, hence the error.